# How can I set collation LOCALIZED in sqlite.net (Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, xamarin

how can I apply a collation to a sqlite.net text column? (Xamarin Android SQLIte.Net Component)

I tried:

```
  public List<CountryInfo> HoleCountryList()
        {
            //var query = conn.Table<CountryInfo>().OrderBy(v=>v.country);
            var query = conn.Query<CountryInfo>("select * from CountryInfo order by country COLLATE LOCALIZED");
            return query.ToList<CountryInfo>();
        }
```

which causes the following error:

> no such collation sequence: LOCALIZED" "SQLite-net" at
>   SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db, System.String query)
>   [0x00012] in /Users/fak/Dro ...

Comment: Can you post the error please?

Comment: Error:"no such collation sequence: LOCALIZED" "SQLite-net"    at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db, System.String query) [0x00012] in /Users/fak/Dro…"

Comment: Copied partial error from comment

Answer (score 0):

As Xamarin SQLite.net does not offer a country specific collation i solved my problem by sorting the result list. This works correctly!

```
 public List<CountryInfo> HoleCountryList()
    {
        try
        {

            var query = conn.Table<CountryInfo>().OrderBy(v=>v.country);
            List<CountryInfo> l = query.ToList<CountryInfo>();
            l = l.OrderBy(x => x.country).ToList();
            return l;
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        { 

            return null; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this! It helped me to find the installed languages.